# CreateProcess execute EXE

Tags: c++, createprocess

I have an application where the user uploads a file to the remote server, the same server to receive this file should run this application. I'm using the CreateProcess method. The problem is, the file directory is already defined in a std :: string, and I'm having difficulties to pass this directory as a parameter to the CreateProcess.

How do I that this directory can be passed to the CreateProcess without errors?

```
    //the client remotely sends the directory where the file will be saved
    socket_setup.SEND_BUFFER("\nRemote directory for upload: ");
    char *dirUP_REMOTE = socket_setup.READ_BUFFER();
    std::string DIRETORIO_UP = dirUP_REMOTE; // variable where it stores the remote directory


        //after uploading this is validation for executing file
if (!strcmp(STRCMP_EXECUTE, EXECUTE_TIME_YES))
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    std::wstring wdirectory;
    int slength = (int)directory.length() + 1;
    int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, directory.c_str(), slength, 0, 0);
    wdirectory.resize(len);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, directory.c_str(), slength, &wdirectory[0], len);
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL, wdirectory.c_str(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi));
}
```

Comment: You are not passing any path+filename to `CreateProcess()`, you are setting both the `lpApplicationName` and `lpCommandLine` to NULL.  One of them has to specify the exe file you want to execute. So what is the real problem? That you do not know how to concatentate strings together? You know how to pass a `std::string` to `CreateProcess()` (via the `c_str()` method). Just make sure you are calling `CreateProcessA()` and not `CreateProcessW()` if you are compiling your app with `UNICODE` enabled.

Comment: You allow users to upload an executable to your server and then you execute it? Yikes!!!!

Comment: `wstring.c_str()` returns a constant string which isn't suitable for passing as the command line, you should allocate a buffer you can modify and pass that instead.  From the documentation: `The Unicode version of this function, CreateProcessW, can modify the contents of this string.`

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions of CreateProcess: CreateProcessA and CreateProcessW (like most similar windows APIs). The right version is used depending on whether you have Unicode enabled.
Here you need to convert your std::string to a std::wstring first, because that CreateProcess is actually a CreateProcessW.

```cpp
std::wstring wdirectory;
int slength = (int)directory.length() + 1;
int len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, directory.c_str(), slength, 0, 0); 
wdirectory.resize(len);
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, directory.c_str(), slength, &wdirectory[0], len);
//...
if (!CreateProcess(NULL,(LPWSTR)wdirectory.c_str(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi));
```

You could also try replacing CreateProcess by a manual call to CreateProcessA and passing the cstring like you tried to do in the question, but then you won't support wide characters :

```
if (!CreateProcessA(NULL, directory.c_str(), NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi));
```

Comment: I tried but I'm having the following error:
argument of type "const wchar_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWSTR"

Comment: @Lulieyt what if you pass &wdirectory[0] instead of wdirectory.c_str() ? Apparently it expects a non-const wchar_t*. Or just manually cast to (LPWSTR) if you want.

Comment: @Lulieyt, yes, have you tried with &wdirectory[0] or with a cast ?

Comment: Now Compile, but the file doesn't execute.

Comment: Then I can't really help you without more information.